# Insert Whatsapp button to Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, whatsapp

I have a javascript code for whatsapp, call buttons from sendstrap.com, I want to add on Laravel website 6 to appear on all pages, I tried public/index but not appear on all pages, is there are a section like header or footer to insert code:

```
<script src="https://app.sendstrap.com/scripts/js/social_button.js?id=1011&key=0XawMTxTmLkvNxa4DxCJspGD0DIfFKiAt4SdiaNz"></script>
```

Comment: try ```resources/view```, laravel template is stored there